# "The last couple of years," "in the last couple of years," or "over the last couple of years?"

Tags: sentence-patterns

I wrote the following:

> With a sigh, Erin put the newspapers aside. Why she could never find what she was looking for in the
>   papers? It'd been a good thing she had stopped reading them **(in/over) the
>   last couple of years.**

Should I use in or over? Or just leave it as it is?

Comment: Since you're asking for writing advice, I'd be remiss not to point out that "Why she could" should be "Why could she".

Comment: You should also either change “in the news” to “in the papers”, or change “stopped reading them” to “stopped reading it” (the former change being preferable to the latter, to my ears). ‘It/them’ will refer back to the nearest antecedent it can find, and skipping over an entire sentence to find ‘newspapers’ in the previous sentence is too far to search for an antecedent; and ‘news’ is singular.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet Thanks! Strange, it seems like I'm getting downvoted in almost all SO sites (except for Writers SE) with no explanation at all. Is a virtual bad spirit following me or something?

Comment: I find if you do a little bit of research before posing your question, you can alleviate a lot of downvotes by including the information you found in your research.  The more information you can provide, the better our answer for you will be.

Comment: @janoChen, it may be because your questions tend to be about writing advice, which is technically off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"In the last couple of years" is actually a shortening of "with*in* the last couple of years", which is saying that she stopped reading them at some point within that time frame.

"Over the last couple of years" means that she had gradually ceased to read them within that time frame, perhaps that she had picked up a newspaper from time to time, but eventually stopped altogether.

Just "the last couple of years" means that she stopped reading them completely throughout the time frame, meaning at no point within it had she read the paper.

The correct phrase to use depends on what you want to say about her reading habits.

Though I do feel the need to point out that, regardless of which one you choose, it isn't actually *true*, because she was reading the newspaper right then and there.  Which is something you may want to consider in choosing the way you want to phrase it.

Comment: Looking through newspapers to find something specific is not necessarily the same as ‘reading the news’. She could easily have stopped reading newspapers in general (in/over) the last couple of years, but still be rummaging through their contents now, looking for something specific.

Comment: @Zibbobz Well, that was an special occasion. Something made her want to check it. Usually, she wouldn't.

Comment: @Why Do You Think That Is True I think you're right. I will remove that sentence.

Comment: @Why Do You Think That Is True Just out of curiosity, why did you downvote?